# Use of traditional set operation - relational algebra

Tags: sql, relational-database, relational-algebra

Many thanks for reading.

Assume the following extract of a table (supplier - parts SP)

```
------------------------
S# | P# | QTY 
------------------------
S1 | P1 | 30
S1 | P2 | 35
S1 | P3 | 40
S2 | P1 | 100
S2 | P2 | 50
S3 | P2 | 30
S4 | P1 | 40
S4 | P2 | 35
```

I am interested in finding out how I can form a query, based -preferebly- only
on union , intersection , difference , product , natural join , division etc operations which will return let's say the supplier numbers who supply all those parts supplied by S2.
I am aware that if I use :

```
SP [S# , P#] DIVIDEBY (SP WHERE S# = 'S2') [P#]
```

I will  get the supplier numbers that supply **at least** all those parts as S2 do but 
I can not imagine on how I can form the query to return only the supplier numbers that supply **exactly** the same parts as supplier S2.

This question is based on a personal scientific interest.

Comment: If you know the supplier numbers that supply at least all those same parts you can just subtract from that those suppliers who supply a part not supplied by S2. For which you need an RA equivalent for `not exists`

Comment: @MartinSmith - Is it possible to make an efficient RA equivalent for not exists, using only the options he mentioned ?

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev Efficiency isn't an aspect of RA as it is just theoretical. But yes googling `not exists relational algebra` should bring back something.

Comment: @MartinSmith - oh yes...lots of results. One from SO. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if this helps. I am using a self join.

```
select *  
from infoz as t1 
inner join infoz as t2
on t1.P# = t2.P#
where t1.S# = 's2'
```

Lets filter this info...

```
select t2.S#, COUNT(t2.P#) as cnt
from infoz as t1 
inner join infoz as t2
on t1.P# = t2.P#
where t1.S# = 's2'
group by t2.S#
```

Now, you can see the count for S2 here and filter by that.

```
select *
from
(
select t2.S#, COUNT(t2.P#) as cnt
from infoz as t1 
inner join infoz as t2
on t1.P# = t2.P#
where t1.S# = 's2'
group by t2.S#
) as r1
where r1.cnt = (select count(t.P#) 
from infoz as t
where t.S# = 's2') and r1.S# ! = 's2'
```

Comment: They don't indicate that the relational algebra operators available to them support aggregation.

Comment: A Brilliant solution as far as I am concerned. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I am not sure if its brilliant because its doing 2 table scans. You might want to check with Bill Karwin, Gordon Linoff, Bluefeet etc...those guys are good. Chenqui.